# describe the task

Tags: java, roman-numerals

I am from Russia. And english isn't my native language :)
 I try to understand the task, but i am not ensured that i correct understood it.

Please, correct me.

http://pastie.org/1811424

```
class DE_Roman
{
   private String romanValue;
   private int    intValue;

   public void romanToInt(Strin romanValue)
   {
      this.romanValue = romanValue;

      int result;
      // ...
      // convert to int and save result in result variable

      this.intValue = result;
   }

   public void intToRoman(int intValue)
   {
      this.intValue = intValue;

      String result = "";
      // ...
      // convert to int and save result in result variable
      this.romanValue = result;
   }

   public void println()
   {
      System.out.println( this.toString() );
   }   

   public String toString()
   {
      return romanValue + " " + intValue;
   }
}
```

is it correct????

about `getInput` i didn't understand... what and where....

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, @johnson! Our system contains a powerful, easy-to-use text/code formatter. Check out the overview [here](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help); that page is accessible by clicking on the brightly colored question mark icon at top right of every post entry/edit box. Please use the formatter for future posts, to make it easier for us to understand your issues and help you. I'll fix this one for you. (Actually, looks like @justkt did that for you while I was writing this.)

Comment: Is this homework?  Are you asking if your program matches the task description in the link?

Comment: about task: something like that. I try to understand functionallity both classes.

Answer (score 0):

Slight deviations:

1. method `romanToInt` shall be call `convertRomanToInt`
2. method `intToRoman` shall be call `convertIntToRoman`
3. I *think* you shall implement an `isValid` method (item 7 is bad english in the task...)

Some other requirements address a second class `DE_RomanTester`, and *that* class shall implement a `public static String getInput(String type)` method. The string tells either to prompt for a roman or an integer input. They don't say *how* the type String should look like, so this should work:

```
 public static final String ROMAN_TYPE   = "String";
 public static final String INTEGER_TYPE = "int";
 public static String getInput(String type) {
   if (type.equals(ROMAN_TYPE)) {
      // prompt for roman number, return int value (as String)
   } else if (type.equals(INTEGER_TYPE)) {
      // prompt for integer number, return roman value (as String)
   }
 }
```

Comment: @johnson - wasn't finished yet ;)